# Python: converting .xls to dataframe to numpy array problem

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to convert .xls files to numpy arrays so as to work with the data. I am currently using pandas library:

```
data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\joaqu\Google Drive\Tesis-III\Pruebas\Con Dispositivo\80W-no 
H\Alteraciones a PID\Cambio de parametros\Kp = 15.5 , Ti = 65, Td = 3.5.xls')
dt = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Time'])
dt=dt.to_numpy()
```

The problem is that when i try to work with the dt array problems come. For example when i try to use the  np.diff an empty array comes as a result.

`np.diff(dt)
    array([], shape=(3444, 0), dtype=int64)`

When printing dt array:

```
print(dt)
[[ 0.  ]
[ 0.  ]
[ 0.  ]
 ...
[33.81]
[33.81]
[33.81]]
```

Wouldn't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
dt = dt["Time"].to_numpy()
```